# pass character "&" by args to R

Tags: r, args, rscript

the following R code is to be execute by command prompt (windows)

```
# Collect arguments
args <- commandArgs(TRUE)

archivo <- as.character(args[1])

cat(archivo)
```

like this

```
C:\Users\Owner\Desktop>Rscript prueba.r "hola&chao"
```

problem is that command prompt respond

```
hola
'chao' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\Owner\Desktop>
```

I need to R accepts the "&" as a character and print it all together in the cat()

What should I do? 
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't an R problem, but a shell problem. You actually executed

```
Rscript prueba.r hola&chao
```

instead of

```
Rscript prueba.r "hola&chao"
```

In the Windows command shell,

```
prog1 & prog2
```

executes both programs in sequence, which is why you see the output of

```
Rscript prueba.r hola
```

followed by the output of

```
chao
```

The other possibility is that `Rscript` is a buggy batch file.

Comment: you're very rigth http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds_shelloverview.mspx?mfr=true ,thanks you